# How to create 'has_one' child record without saving to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model we'll call `Parent` with a `has_one` relationship with a model we'll call `Child`.

The relationship in its entirety in the Parent model is:

`has_one :child, :dependent => :destroy, autosave: false`

If I call `Parent.new`, the record is not saved to the database until I call `save`.

If I call `Child.new`, same thing.

But, if I do either of the following, the child record is automatically saved to the database without calling save.

`parent.child = Child.new`

or

`child = Child.new # not saved yet
parent.child = child # automatically saved to db`

Anyone know how to prevent automatically saving the child to the database?

The goal is to only save the child record when I click hit the parent contorller's update function.

Comment: This is rails useful magic. What is your usecase?

Comment: do like `has_one :child, :autosave => true`.. and try. let me know.  If you do this - *always save the associated object or destroy it if marked for destruction, when saving the parent object.*

Comment: If a user is poking around in the system but not wanting to save anything, we want the user to not worry about changing anything unless they hit the "Update" or "Save" button.

Comment: @MatthewGreenfield have you tried.. what I said ?

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do something like `parent.child = Child.build` to no avail.

What seems to be the solution is:

`parent.build_child`

This creates the child record, applies the association, but doesn't yet save the child record to the database. When you do parent.save, the child record is saved!

Comment: This works when the records are being created. But if you need to replace an existing child of an existing parent (like in your example), the previous child is being deleted as soon as you try to build a new child (that is, before you save the parent), which leaves you with no child, if you choose not to save the parent. This is not that intuitive.
Also have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53243674/build-methods-for-has-one-though-has-one
and here:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17368