# build methods for has_one though has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-one-through

Rails 5.1.2
Ruby 2.5.3

I understand there are multiple ways to impliment this relationship, however, this question is more about why the following doesn't work rather than solving a real world problem.

**`has_many` setup**

```
class Subscriber < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions, inverse_of: :subscriber
  has_many :promotions, through: :subscriptions, inverse_of: :subscriptions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscriptions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :promotions
end

class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subscriber, inverse_of: :subscriptions
  belongs_to :promotion, inverse_of: :subscriptions
end

class Promotion < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions, inverse_of: :promotion
  has_many :subscribers, through: :subscriptions, inverse_of: :subscriptions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscriptions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscribers
end
```

In the above `Subscriber` model which is setup to use `has_many` relationships following would work:

```
s = Subscriber.new
s.subscriptions.build
# OR
s.promotions.build
```

Following that, I would expect `Subscriber` to behave the same way with `has_one` relationships

**`has_one` setup**

```
class Subscriber < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :subscription, inverse_of: :subscriber
  has_one :promotion, through: :subscription, inverse_of: :subscriptions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscription
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :promotion
end

class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subscriber, inverse_of: :subscription
  belongs_to :promotion, inverse_of: :subscriptions
end

class Promotion < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions, inverse_of: :promotion
  has_many :subscribers, through: :subscriptions, inverse_of: :subscription

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscriptions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscribers
end
```

However, attempting to build the nested `promotion` association with the equivalent `has_one` build methods results in a `NoMethodError (undefined method 'build_promotion' for #<Subscriber:0x00007f9042cbd7c8>)` error

```
s = Subscriber.new
s.build_promotion
```

However, this does work:

```
s = Subscriber.new
s.build_subscription
```

I feel it's logical that one should expect to build nested `has_one` relationships in the same way one builds `has_many`.

Is this a bug or by design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the code, when you call has_one, it creates the `build_`, `create_` and `create_..!` methods ONLY if the reflection is "constructable"

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b2eb1d1c55a59fee1e6c4cba7030d8ceb524267c/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/singular_association.rb#L16

```
define_constructors(mixin, name) if reflection.constructable?
```

Now, checking the `constructable?` method, it returns the result of `calculate_constructable` https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ed1eda271c7ac82ecb7bd94b6fa1b0093e648a3e/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L452

And for the HasOne class, it returns false if you use the `:through` option https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ed1eda271c7ac82ecb7bd94b6fa1b0093e648a3e/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L723

```
def calculate_constructable(macro, options)
  !options[:through]
end
```

So, I'd say it's not a bug, it's made like that by design. I don't know the reason though, maybe it feels logical but I guess there's some things to consider that are not that simple.